# Determine Stiffness of IVP $ \dot{y}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 80 & 4 + i \\ 0 & -5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -800 \end{pmatrix} y(t) $ , $y(0) = y_0$

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We're asked whether the following IVP is stiff:
$$
\dot{y}(t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 80 & 4 + i \\
0 & -5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -800
\end{pmatrix} y(t) 
$$
$$y(0) = y_0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix is upper triangular, thus the eignevalues are $-2$, $-5$ and $-800$. All eigenvalues have a negative real part. Also $$\frac{max| \lambda _i|}{min|\lambda _i|} = 400$$ which is relatively large. Thus, this IVP is in fact stiff.